# How to generate unique Class or ID and add to the selected HTML elements

Tags: jquery

I am trying to generating unique Class or ID and add them where is the header class or any other class. Each generating Class or ID have to be unique and add it to the following any HTML elements. Trying to figure it out for last couple of hours and still no luck :(

```
<div class="header>
<div class="text">
<div class="image">
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="header>
<div class="text">
<div class="image">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see where you've made an effort, nor do I have any sense of context. Please clarify.

Comment: What is that HTML supposed to show? I have no idea what you're asking for help with; you may wish to clarify your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
$('.text, .image, .header').each(function(id) {
   $(this).attr('id', 'elem-' + id);
});
```

Comment: This works perfectly. I did pretty similar thing but I missed the .attr() method. Thank you so much

Comment: I'm glad. Please don't forget to mark it as accepted answer if you are satisfied, so other users can see that it is the correct answer.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know what's wrong with the other people. I already tried to accepted this answer but it looks like I don't have enough reputation to make it.

And I was trying to figure this out like for last 3 hours but I was missing the .attr() method. And here people is providing negative feedback and it could suspend my account. If someone dislike it then he/she always have an option to close the tab

Comment: Well, voting is used to keep the standards high. Down-votes should motivate people to improve their questions. However, I am almost certain, that there are no limitations for accepting answers (you might have confused it with up-voting). Have you tried clicking the green tick mark?